# Rspec 'have(x).items' test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I am building a quiz application where each **User** *has many* **Exams**, and each **Exam** *has many* **Facts** *through* a **Problems** table:

**app/models/exam.rb:**

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :assign_facts
    belongs_to :user
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    has_many :problems
    has_many :facts, through: :problems

    def assigned?(fact)
        problems.find_by(fact_id: fact.id)
    end

    def assign!(fact)
        problems.create!(fact_id: fact.id)
    end

    private

        def assign_facts
            facts = Fact.all.sample(10)
            facts.each do |fact|
                self.assign!(fact)
            end
        end

end
```

**app/models/problem.rb**

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :exam
    belongs_to :fact
    validates :exam_id, presence: true
    validates :fact_id, presence: true
end
```

You'll notice that each time an Exam is created the model assigns it a certain number of Facts

```
    after_create :assign_facts
```

This is done through a callback function that grabs some random Facts from the database and assigns them to the Exam.

```
    def assign_facts
        facts = Fact.all.sample(10)
        facts.each do |fact|
            self.assign!(fact)
        end
    end
```

All of this seems to work fine. I'm able to test this functionality from the web interface and check the results in the database and everything seems to work as intended.

My problem is that the rspec test I wrote before implementation is still failing:

```
    subject { @exam }

    its(:facts) { should have(10).items}
```

I'm not entirely clear on how to use *should have(10).items*. The *items* I'm checking for here are the 10 Facts each Exam has through the Problems table. What am I doing wrong?
Please see the complete test file below.

**spec/models/exam_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Exam do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { @exam = user.exams.create }

    subject { @exam }

    it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
    it { should respond_to(:problems)}
    it { should respond_to(:facts) }

    it { should be_valid }

    its(:facts) { should have(10).items}

    describe "when user_id is not present" do
        before { @exam.user_id = nil }
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "assigning facts" do
        let(:fact) { FactoryGirl.create(:fact) }
        before do
            @exam.assign!(fact)
        end

        it { should be_assigned(fact) }
        its(:facts) { should include(fact) }
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `after_create` callbacks are invoked after the record has been *saved*. Since you are just doing a `build` of the exam, so there is no internal `save` and thus no callback. If you change your code to `subject { @exam = user.exams.create }` you'll not have this problem.

As has been noted in the comment thread initiated by @JosephL, this spec depends on the database being prepopulated with facts. A generally preferred approach is to create whatever test data you need as part of your examples.

As an aside, note that use of `should` is deprecated in RSpec 3 and `its` is moving to a separate gem. You might want to consider moving to the `expect` syntax if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi @peter. Thanks for the feedback. I changed the code to `@exam = user.exams.create` but kept it in the before block because adding it to the `subject{}` block broke my `assign!` test at the bottom. Unfortunately I'm still getting false positives from this test. I modified the code above to show the current test. Any ideas? This is driving me crazy!

Comment: False positives? So you're not still failing to `have(10).items`?

Comment: `Fact.all.sample(10)` Do you have any facts in your test DB or will this fail?

Comment: @TomClowers - As a follow-up to the previous comment from @JosephL, note that `[].sample(10) == []`, so you're "assign_facts` method will not assign any facts if there are no facts in the database.

Comment: Hi @PeterAlfvin and @JosephL, yes my test, just as it is written above is failing. I already have a rake task in `lib/tasks/sample_data.rake` to fill in the database with 50 sample facts, so the problem isn't there. I am able to use this functionality from the web and check my results on the rails console to see that everything is working as intended, it's the test itself that is broken. Once again, I really appreciate the feedback, guys.

Comment: Does your rake task add the sample facts to your development AND test db's or just development? can you try `rails console test` and see if it works in your test environment?

Comment: You're right @JosephL, when I run the rails console in test mode, none of the data for the facts is there. I appreciate your patience on this, I see it's what you were trying to tell me before. I'm still looking into how to get the sample data I need in the test environment. How can I fix this? Is there a way to bring that data over from the development environment into the tests?

Comment: Unless there is a performance issue that requires a one-time setup, you should just create the facts as part of your RSpec test. I've updated the answer to reflect this.